# Refresh all queries in Excel file via Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have an Excel file that I run a Python script on (I use Python 3.11.4). The Excel file has multiple queries that should all be refreshed automatically when I run the script.

I tried different solutions that were already shared in this forum, but don't do the trick for me.
For instance, I tried the following code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
Xlsx = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = True
Xlsx.Visible = True
book = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open(<file link.xlsx>)
book.RefreshAll()
Xlsx.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
book.Save()
book.Close()
Xlsx.Quit()
del book
del Xlsx
```

Here, there is the following problem: The code opens the respective Excel file and starts refreshing the queries. Yet, the processes never finishes (e.g., I was waiting for half an hour and the file was still updating).

Has anybody encountered the same issue or has an idea how to resolve this?